# how to get the prediction or results from custom vision api?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, computer-vision

I try using custom vision service that could read bank notes. I came up with this code shown below(through the code samples here...
[Microsoft custom vision sample codes](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57982f59b5964e36841e22dfbfe78fc1/operations/5a3044f608fa5e06b890f164)

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
    RequestBody requestBody = null;

    requestBuilder.addHeader("Prediction-Key","___________________________");
    requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8"), output.toByteArray());

    requestBuilder.method("POST", requestBody);

    requestBuilder.url("https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v1.1/Prediction/__________/image");

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        return response.body().string();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Exception: response code " + response.code());
    }
```

And based from this [link](https://www.henkboelman.com/recognizing-things-with-the-custom-vision-service/) it uses an sdk from microsoft to get results. However, I want to build an android app.
How am I be able to get the tag result and its prediction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a way to send an http request and get the results in android?

Comment: Yes. But when I try to debug it, it returns a lot of data but I can't find the exact tag or prediction.

Comment: What do you mean by "read bank notes"? Do you mean you want to read text from an image?

Comment: "Microsoft custom vision service" is used to identify object by training the machine(device) using a set of images.

Comment: So, what do you want: identify objects or read text?

Comment: I'm already done with the training part wherein the pictures that I've train are peso bills. I am just having a hard time implementing it to my code.

Comment: I've never used "Microsoft custom vision service", but I'm very interested in machine learning. The only example I found that relates " Microsoft custom vision service" to android is [link](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/05/12/food-classification-custom-vision-service/) (at the end you can find an android application example that is also found on github). By the way you can use tensorflow instead of Microsoft vision service.